# Is it possible to customize the AvalonEdit search panel button icons?

Tags: wpf, avalonedit

I need to customize the dropdown search panel to match my application but I can seem to figure out how. I am using C# WPF .net Framework 4.7.2

I have tried the below style but it does not recognize Search in AvalonEdit.

```
xmlns:search="clr-namespace:ICSharpCode.AvalonEdit.Search"
<Style TargetType="search:SearchPanel">
```

[Image of options I have](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lq2Io.png)

Comment: Out of curiosity, why are you still targeting 4.7.2 and not 4.8? I cannot think of any legitimate reason for anyone to not target 4.8 - every platform that ran 4.7.2 can update to 4.8, and 4.8 is ostensibly 100% source-compatible with 4.7.2 applications.

Comment: There was no real reason except lack of knowledge. I am self taught. I will change it to 4.8 next opportunity I get. Thank you for pointing that out.